# Writing to files safely in c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

Let's say you have a txt file, it currently holds content that's important. Currently the content is at such

```
"I like blue cats and yellow dogs."
```

but you want to update said content.

```
std::ofstream myFile;
myFile.open("file.txt");
myFile << "I like " << catColorStr << " cats and " << dogColorStr << " dogs.";
myFile.close();
```

But let's say for some reason your program crashes between line two and three or maybe the user's power cuts out or they use end process in windows task manager etc. Well you have just deleted the entire contents of file.txt. How do you go about accounting for this typically?

Is the typical way of dealing with this to open it as read only copy the contents to your program. Then copy that to a new tempfile or something. Then write to your actual file and if that succeeds deleting your tempfile else upon start you say your actual file = your temp file?

Comment: If you want to ensure that there is no data loss even in the case of a power failure, you will probably also want to make sure that you are using a [journaling file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system).

Comment: I dont suppose you know of any good resources to learn how to implement a journaling file system using c++?

Comment: You don't need to implement your own filesystem for what you want to do. Most common file systems, such as [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) and [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), are journaling file systems. My only point is that you should not be using a file system that is not resistant to power failures. I believe some example of such filesystems are [ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) and [FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table).

Comment: Another possibility of data loss from power failure arises from the fact that there are several layers of write caches between your program and the drive. This is a big problem for database systems. See [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/wal-reliability.html) of the manual of the PostgreSQL database system for further information.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, you create a new file, write to it, close it, then rename the new file to the old file.

```
std::ofstream myFile;
myFile.open("file.txt.new");
myFile << "I like " << catColorStr << " cats and " << dogColorStr << " dogs.";
myFile.close();
sys::filesystem::rename("file.txt.new", "file.txt"); 
// or POSIX rename or Windows or...
```

(Error checking omitted for brevity)

The rename operation atomically deletes the old file and gives the new file the old name. If somebody pulls the power cord in the middle of it, it's your operating system's problem, not yours. Modern OSes are quite good at dealing with it.